# Выполнение js после получения сервером post запроса

Tags: php, javascript, post

Имеется telegram бот для авторизации пользователей. Пользователь нажимает кнопку авторизации на сайте, получает токен, отправляет его боту. Бот проверяет токен и выдает проверочный код. Затем пользователь вводит этот проверочный код в окно, где получен токен. Если проверочный код соответствует токену, то пользователь авторизуется.

Необходимо убрать из этой цепочки получение и вбивание проверочного кода. Т.е. ботом отправлять post запрос на сайт, а при получении post запроса проверять данные и запустить скрипт авторизации.

Только вот не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы скрипт авторизации получил этот запрос и выполнился там, где был получен токен. Есть ли решения этой задачи?

P.S. Бот и сайт фактически находятся на одном сервере и имеют общую базу. В базе создана таблица в которой хранятся пары токен-код. Туда же прикрепляется id юзера, которого нужно авторизовать, после получения ботом токена от пользователя. Как вариант, можно опрашивать базу раз в секунду. Как только в строке появится id юзера, то проверить данные и авторизовать. Но в этом случае будет лишняя нагрузка на сервак.

Comment: слишком общий вопрос, в чем проблема отправить запрос и по приходу ответа тут же его обработать?

Comment: бот должен проверить, что запрос пришел именно от нужного юзера. юзернейм в телеграме == юзернейм на сайте. а если сразу отправить запрос, то как бот поймет, от какого юзера пришел запрос?

Comment: Используй AJAX запрос и обрабатывай результат. Может быть я не понял смысла. Лучше не писать, что бот, для чего и т.д., а указать суть (браузер, сервер, страница...)